# Insert Row number from match into query

Tags: excel

I have an if query on several cells that update from an api that looks like so:

`=IF(Scrapes!B15<1,0, IF(Exact(Scrapes!F15,"-"), 0,Scrapes!F15))`

what i would like to do is search for a row containing data like so:

`=MATCH(A3, Scrapes!A2:A94,0)+1`

and insert that row number into the If query above so it would be as follows:

`=IF(Scrapes!B{RowNumber}<1,0, IF(Exact(Scrapes!F{RowNumber},"-"), 0,Scrapes!F{RowNumber}))`

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try `INDEX` function:

```
=IF(INDEX(Scrapes!B:B,MATCH(A3, Scrapes!A2:A94,0)+1)<1,0, IF(Exact(INDEX(Scrapes!F:F,MATCH(A3, Scrapes!A2:A94,0)+1),"-"), 0,INDEX(Scrapes!F:F,MATCH(A3, Scrapes!A2:A94,0)+1)))
```